# Handling error: UnsupportedGrantTypeException, Unsupported grant type: password

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up spring security with oauth2.0 in my application. and I am getting an exception:

> UnsupportedGrantTypeException, Unsupported grant type: password

Is there anything that I am missing in configuration?

error logs:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.UnsupportedGrantTypeException: Unsupported grant type: password
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:134) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: Show your authorization server configuration. How did you register yor client?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Oauth server doesn't support password grant type. This one is used for getting "access tokens". I think that you should look for grant types handled by your OAuth  server

Comment: yes, this may be the condition but where is the problem.any suggestions about that?
as i found on internet : ".authenticationManager(authenticationManager); " is to be used in " public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exceptionmethod {}" method.
but when autowiring   authenticationManager interface, getting authenticationManager is unable to autowired.

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration for your authorization server, when you extend `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, you can set up the authorized grant types for each of your clients.

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("client1")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .secret("{noop}secret")
            .scopes("read")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600_000_000);
}
```

There is a full example in the spring-security authorization server [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e7f93f221d4b828d336627f5147a3edd02a8c28d/samples/boot/oauth2authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java#L94).